# Jquery Date Format with JavaScript

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery and want to format a date. I don't want to have to import another plug-in for jQuery. I have found a solution that works in JavaScript i.e.

```
var now = new Date(); 

var curr_date = d.getDate();

var curr_month = d.getMonth();

curr_month++;

var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

$('##optionButtons').append('<a href="##"class="btn">' 
+ curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" 
+ curr_year + '</a> </ br>');
```

However, when I add the date shown in the example below I get the following error, why?

```
var d = value.CREATED;

var curr_date = d.getDate();

var curr_month = d.getMonth();

curr_month++;

var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

$('##optionButtons').append('<a href="##">' 
+ curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" 
+ curr_year + '</a> </ br>');
```

ERROR ##################### 
 d.getDate is not a function
 ###########################

The value of 'value.CREATED' is October, 25 2012 00:00:00+0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to send the date in milliseconds from the server, and then create the date object in javascript as new Date(milliseconds).

See reference here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

OR

```
var d = new Date(value.created); //new Date('October, 25 2012 00:00:00+0000')
```

EDIT: Considering your value.created to be a string, I could parse it in the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y6bcR/) here.

I hope this would work.

Comment: the value of 'value.CREATED' is from an ajax call which I cannot change server side. this is the format I have to work with October, 25 2012 00:00:00+0000

Comment: var d =  new Date(value.created); gives me NaN NaN NaN?

Comment: The problem is then with the value.created element. See a running demo http://jsfiddle.net/y6bcR/

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse. Parse your string first and than pass it into Date.parse.

Answer (score 0):

The code: `var d = value.CREATED;` does not (somehow) return a `Date`. That's why your call to one of its functions `var curr_date = d.getDate();` is illegal. If you show in your example where the variable `value` come's from, we are maybe able to find the bug.

Comment: $.each(data.DATA, function(index, value){

Answer (score 0):

The date format you are using is not valid.

```
var d = new Date('October, 25 2012 00:00:00');
```